# On different norms of the interpolating operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, measure-theory, approximation-theory, interpolation

Let $[a,b]$ be an interval in real line . Given any function $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ and set $A \subseteq [a,b]$ of size $n+1$, there exists a unique polynomial $p_{f,A,n}(x)$ of degree $n$ such that $f(a)=p_{f,A,n}(a),\forall a\in A$. Such a polynomial is called the interpolating polynomial of $f$ with nodes $A$. Due to this, given $A\subseteq [a,b]$ with $n+1=|A|$, we can consider a linear map $X_{A,n} : C[a,b]\to C[a,b]$ such that $X_{A,n}(f)=p_{A,f,n}$ . Then $X_{A,n}$ is  a projection i.e. $X^2_{A,n}=X_{A,n}$. Equip the domain $C[a,b]$ with $L^{\infty}$ norm and co-domain $C[a,b]$ with $L^p$ norm.

My question is: For which $p\in [1,\infty]$, is $X_{A,n} : (C[a,b],||.||_{\infty} ) \to (C[a,b],||.||_p )$ continuous for every $A \subseteq [a,b]$ of size $n+1$ and also that for every sequence $\{A_n\}$ of subsets of $[a,b]$ with each $A_n$ of size $n+1$, the sequence $||X_{A_n,n}||$ is not uniformly bounded w.r.t. $n$ ?